# How to implement an updateTodo function in a todo list?

Tags: reactjs, setstate, onsubmit

I wanna update the todo item in the todo list but I have some troubles understanding this function, like why does setState in the function submitTodo still set the id and value the same like in the useState above...can anybody help me to understand this function better? thank you so much!

This is the function:

TodoList.js:

```
const updateTodo = (todoId, newValue) => {
    if (!newValue.text || /^\s*$/.test(newValue.text)) {
      return;
    }

    setTodos(prev => prev.map(item => (item.id === todoId ? newValue : item)));
  };
```

Todo.js:

```
const [edit, setEdit] = useState({
    id: null,
    value: ''
  });

  const submitUpdate = value => {
    updateTodo(edit.id, value);
    setEdit({
      id: null,
      value: ''
    });
  };

  if (edit.id) {
    return <TodoForm edit={edit} onSubmit={submitUpdate} />;
  }
```

Comment: The parameter given to the useState function is the initial state. The setEdit call you are talking about sets the edit state back to its initial state.

Comment: but why do you have to set the edit state back to its initial state tho?

Comment: Is this not your code?? If you don't want to reset those form values when the user hits submit, then remove that line.

Comment: which line do you mean?

Comment: `setEdit({value:""})` Do you want to set the edit value to empty string when a user is submitting an update? If so that's what that code says it does. Otherwise remove it.

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work either, here my full codes, if you have time you can check to help me: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-wind-s30er?file=/src/components/Todo.js. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because after you update the todo via updateTodo() function, you'll need to clear what is stored in state for future use, hence setting it back to what it was initialised to in the useState declaration. This is usually bundled after the actual update, as a good state management practice.